# Detect if system has specific character availiable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website which uses a lot of goose emojis ().
But the problem is that not all devices support this emoji. On some devices just an empty box (see image) appears.

If think its maybe because the emoji was added in 2022 and some systems are not up to date (https://emojipedia.org/goose).

Is there any way in JavaScript to detect if the user has the goose emoji available on their system and maybe replace it with a duck () when not?

[image: empty box]

Comment: [There is likely a dupe among these](https://www.google.com/search?q=detect+emoji+support+site:stackoverflow.com)